# With SSH2 and phpseclib, how do I upload a file to Amazon EC2 server in PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver, ssh2

I am trying to create a web interface where users can upload an image file, and this file will be sent to my Amazon EC2 server. I was told to use phpseclib instead of PHP SDK for this and I have tried the following code:

**testform.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Upload Files</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
    include('Net/SSH2.php');
    include('Crypt/RSA.php');

    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents('KeyKey.ppk'));

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('domain-name-of-my-server');
    if (!$ssh->login('ec2-user', $rsa)) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    $target_dir = "/home/ec2-user/Test1";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $uploadOK = 1;

    strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $imageArr=explode('.',$image); //first index is file name and second index file type
    $rand=rand(10000,99999);
    $newImageName=$imageArr[0].$rand.'.'.$imageArr[1];

    $uploadPath = "/home/ec2-user/Test1".$newImageName;

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) 
    {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) 
    {
        echo("Sorry, your file was not uploaded.");
    } 
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    else 
    {
        if (ssh2_scp_send($ssh, $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $uploadPath, 0644)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }


    echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
    echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
}
?>
```

The connection to my server looks fine, but this line

> line 50: if (ssh2_scp_send($ssh, $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
>   $uploadPath, 0644)

is giving me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   ssh2_scp_send() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php:50 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 50

I figured that something is wrong with the paths that I have provided to ssh2_scp_send() function and I have no idea how to fix it.

I have looked at threads on here with the same questions (like [Upload file to Amazon EC2 server from website by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53832238/upload-file-to-amazon-ec2-server-from-website-by-php)), but they are mostly using PHP SDK.

Would anyone please offer some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that you are calling an `undefined function`.

Have you installed all necessary packages and extension on your instance?

```
yum install gcc php-devel php-pear libssh2 libssh2-devel make
```

Comment: Do I install this on my remote server? Is there a way I can check if my dependencies are installed correctly? I tried to install this on my instance, and the error seems to be saying that I already have them installed.

Answer (score 0):

idk why you're trying to use phpseclib *and* libssh2.

Anyway, try this:

```
#
#-----[ FIND ]------------------------------------------
#
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('domain-name-of-my-server');
#
#-----[ REPLACE WITH ]----------------------------------
#
    $ssh = new Net_SFTP('domain-name-of-my-server');
#
#-----[ FIND ]------------------------------------------
#
        if (ssh2_scp_send($ssh, $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $uploadPath, 0644)) {
#
#-----[ REPLACE WITH ]----------------------------------
#
        if ($ssh->put($uploadPath, $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE) {
            $sftp->chmod(0644, $uploadPath);
```