# How do I upload files to Amazon EC2 server in php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpseclib, amazon-efs

I have installed Apache server on one EC2 instance to serve files in Amazon EFS file system. Then I mount EFS under apache root `/var/www/html`. I have created subfolders under this path. Now I would like to upload files to that folder from my web application using php.

I have tried with phpseclib/SFTP. Am I doing is right?

```
            include_once($dir.'vendor/autoload.php');

            $key = PublicKeyLoader::load(file_get_contents($ppkpath));

            $ssh = new SFTP('ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com');
            if (!$ssh->login('ec2-user', $key)) {
                exit('Login Failed');
            }else{
                echo "Logged in"; 
            }
            $file_name = $_FILES['file_path']['name'];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['file_path']['tmp_name'];
            $uploadPath = "/var/www/html/efsmount/Foldername";
            //if (ssh2_scp_send($ssh, $_FILES["file_path"]["tmp_name"], $uploadPath, 0644)) {
            if ($ssh->put($uploadPath, $_FILES["file_path"]["tmp_name"], SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE)) {
                $sftp->chmod(0644, $uploadPath);
                echo "Uploaded";
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "Upload Failed";     
            }
```

Output is: `Upload Failed`. No other error messages.

Comment: [Check this may this help, This is somewhat like I tried some when I'm learning AWS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53832238/upload-file-to-amazon-ec2-server-from-website-by-php)

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Thank you. But this is for S3. I want EFS upload.

Comment: There is no document for EFS upload. So I am trying with sftp

Comment: check error_logs file to see what error php is giving

Comment: error_log shows **TCP/IP option not available!** @HelloWorld

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution.

In order to upload files from local machine to the EC2 instance, you’ll need to allow the ec2-user account to manipulate files in the apache document root.

I did [this steps](https://medium.com/theloudcloud/launching-a-local-php-application-in-amazon-ec2-instance-73c090ee0e9d) to change directory permissions. After that I run my code. It upload the files successfully.

My modified code:

```
            include_once($dir.'vendor/autoload.php');

            $key = PublicKeyLoader::load(file_get_contents($ppkpath));

            $ssh = new SFTP('xx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
            if (!$ssh->login('ec2-user', $key)) {
                exit('Login Failed');
            }else{
                echo "Logged in"; 
            }
            if (!empty($_FILES) && isset($_FILES)) {                
               $file_name = $_FILES['file_path']['name'];
               $file_tmp =$_FILES['file_path']['tmp_name'];
               $uploadPath = "/var/www/html/efsmount/Foldername/";
               $path = $uploadPath.$file_name;
            if ($ssh->put($path, $_FILES["file_path"]["tmp_name"], SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE)) {
                echo "Uploaded";
   
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "Upload Failed";
               
            }
           }
```